# yolo8 bounding box live streams

Tags: python, opencv, yolov8

Have this python code reading alive stream camera and it can detect the forklifts as class. However it won't draw the bounding boxes of the identified object. Any suggestions? I tired many things with no good results. I can't get it to draw boxes around the object detected. I am trying to train this on a real time streaming camera.

```
import cv2
import ultralytics as yolo
 
# RTSP URL
RTSP_URL = 'rtsp://oursteamdetailshere'

# Load the model
model = yolo.YOLO('forkliftweights.pt')

# Open the video stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL)

# Desired display resolution
width = 1366
height = 768

# Bounding box color and line thickness
box_color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green
box_thickness = 2

# Label text color and font settings
text_color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
font_size = 0.9

# Increase the confidence threshold
confidence_threshold = 0.5

while True:
    # Read frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    # Make prediction on the current frame
    results = model.predict(frame, conf=confidence_threshold)

    # Check if results is not empty
    if results and len(results[0]) > 0:
        # Draw bounding boxes and labels on the frame
        for res in results[0]:
            # Convert torch.Tensor to numpy array
            res_np = res.numpy()

            # Check if res_np has at least 6 elements (4 for the bounding box, 1 for the confidence score, and 1 for the class ID)
            if len(res_np) < 6:
                continue

            box = res_np[:4]
            confidence = res_np[4]
            class_id = res_np[5]

            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
            label = f'{model.names[int(class_id)]}: {confidence:.2f}'

            # Draw bounding box rectangle
            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), box_color, box_thickness)

            # Draw label text
            frame = cv2.putText(frame, label, (int(x1), int(y1) - 10), font, font_size, text_color, box_thickness)

    # Resize frame
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow("Forklift Weights", frame)

    # Exit if Q key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the video capture
cap.release()

# Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if result statement is "True", first try to check whether res_np is allocated or not with printing.
in other hand it would be possible that converting from tensor to numpy "res_np = res.numpy()" has trouble that you should use other methods; i think you have to use .cpu() in order to do that.